# magento 2 Warning: Illegal offset type in xxxx\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\CategoryRepository.php on line 133

Tags: magento2, product, cache

I am enable magento 2 admin cache then product view page not working show warning but i am disable cache then working fine,
warning see the following screenshot[image]
Warning: Illegal offset type in `xxxxxx\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\CategoryRepository.php on line 133`

Comment: Please check error on `\var\report` error number

Comment: category id is sent null on that page i think